# How to implement objective C protocol in swift class?

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift-protocols

```
@protocol LibraryPaymentStatusProtocol <NSObject>
@required
-(void)paymentStatus:(NSString*)message;
@optional
-(void)onError:(NSException *)exception;
-(void)tryAgain;
-(void)cancelTransaction;
@end
```

This protocol I want to implement in my swift class. This protocol is present in BDViewController.h file which is inside the Library. I imported the library successfully in my swift project not getting access to this protocol. What is the additional thing I am missing? Thanks in advance.

In my Swift class, I simply want to implement like normal protocol like below

```
class mainTabViewController: LibraryPaymentStatusProtocol {

// MARK : - Payment status protocol method
    func paymentStatus(_ message: String!) {
      
    }

}
```

Comment: Please share how you use it in your Swift class.

Comment: @koen Just added in the question thanks for the support

Comment: As already mentioned in the answers, you need a Bridging Header, see the Apple docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift

Comment: yeah was a blunder mistake @koen Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in the [bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift)

```
#import "BDViewController.h"
```

maybe it will solve your problem. Let me know if it is helpful.

Comment: I'm glad it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Swift bridging header and include your Objective-C file there.

```
//  <ProjectName>-Bridging-Header.h

#import "BDViewController.h" // In which you have written LibraryPaymentStatusProtocol
```

Then you can implement the required method as

```
func paymentStatus(_ message: String?) {

}
```